# problem in connecting studio management to sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

I had installed SQL Server 2008, but faced some complications with that. I then installed SQL Server 2005, and now installed SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2005 successfully.

I am not able to connnect to the server name it suggests.

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to POONAM-C586A95C\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionDlg)

It doesn't show any other option of SQL Server name, though I changed the name as I remembered but for no good.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Depends, Is your SQL Server running OR I mean is it listening to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you're trying to connect to the 2008 instance with the 2005 SSMS. It's not clear whether you un-installed the 2008 instance.

Suggest [installing the SQL Server 2008 SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en).

Confirm/modify as needed that you're running the SQL Server instance that you require. This will show you which instances are available.

[image]

Comment: I dont think so coz i even tried to change the name but same error occurs. Still, is there eny way to check the instace name?

Comment: I just checked and found that SQL Server 2005 configuration manager says "there are no items to show in this view". Means SQL Server 2005 instance is not running. Do I need to uninstall sql server 2008?

Comment: problem solved- i reinstalled sql server 2005. it worked without uninstalling sql server 2008 though i will uninstall it. @all thanks for ur support

Comment: I tried installing ssms 2008 but it gave an error that i need to install visual studio 2008 which is quite heavy. so i again switched to sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

I would also check to make sure that you're connecting to the correct port. I'm come across a similar error before and the solution was to specify the port to connect to, i.e.

compname\instancename,portnum